# Tweepy can't create_tweet() with media

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I've recently been trying to create a twitter bot, and one of my tests is posting a media file as a tweet. Unfortunately, I've ran into some roadblocks. I'll put the related code here:

```
filename = 'vid.mp4'
media = api.media_upload(filename, chunked=True, media_category="tweet_video")
client.create_tweet(text='test', media_ids=str(media.media_id))
```

The error I receive is:

tweepy.errors.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
$.media_ids: there must be a maximum of 4 items in the array

I'm a little lost here, honestly. I'm already having to use both v1.1 and v2 twitter because I only have an 'essentials' developer account currently, but it seems like this should work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Tweepy documentation ([here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet)), `media_ids` is supposed to be a list.

```py
media = api.media_upload(filename, chunked=True, media_category="tweet_video")
media_ids = [media.media_id]  # It can be a list of integers
client.create_tweet(text='test', media_ids=media_ids)
```